# Contact form won't submit data

Tags: php, json, forms

I have a JSON code in a sendemail.php file for my Bootstrap 3 contact form. The form is able to send an email to the specified email address but there is no data being submitted. I get blank emails with labels and the header 'unknown sender'. Please help solve this.

This is the bootsrap form code chunk

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
                    <p>Please contact us using the form or our contact details are available here if you'd like to contact us via Email or Phone.</p>
                    <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
                    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" required placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control" required placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="Message" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/.col-sm-6-->
```

This is the main.js code where the AJAX for contact form is present

```
jQuery(function($) {

$(function(){
    $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000,
        pause: false
    });
});

//Ajax contact
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});

//smooth scroll
$('.navbar-nav > li').click(function(event) {
    if(!$( this ).attr( 'href' ).match(/^#/)) return; 
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).find('>a').prop('hash');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 500);
});

//scrollspy
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
    var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
})

//PrettyPhoto
$("a.preview").prettyPhoto({
    social_tools: false
});

//Isotope
$(window).load(function(){
    $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
    $portfolio.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'li',
        layoutMode : 'fitRows'
    });
    $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
    $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
        $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

This is the sendemail.php code

```
<?php    
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$name = $_POST['Name']; 
$email = $_POST['Email']; 
$subject = $_POST['Subject']; 
$message = $_POST['Message']; 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'myemail@domain.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

?>

Comment: The name attribute is missing from your inputs.

Comment: I could be wrong (wouldn't be the first or last time) but `@mail` should/could be just `mail`?
`$success = mail(to, subject, body, params);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I've added the attributes to my HTML code and also tried mail() instead of @mail() and that did not work either. Do you think I have to tweak something on the server to get JSON working?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name attribute in your html input tags

This is required for the server side variables, for example:

```
$name = $_POST['Name'];
```

will get value from

```
<input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" required placeholder="Name">
```

---

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="Name" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="Email" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea  name="Message" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" value="Send Message">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['Name'],$_POST['Email'],$_POST['Subject'],$_POST['Message'])){
    $name = $_POST['Name']; 
    $email = $_POST['Email']; 
    $subject = $_POST['Subject']; 
    $message = $_POST['Message']; 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'myemail@domain.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    $response = array();

    if($success){
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Email sent!';
    }else{
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'Email sent!';
    }
}else{
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'post variables are not set';
}

echo json_encode($response);
//die;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the attributes to my HTML tags but it didn't work.

Comment: @RobGudipudi please copy paste the code in my edit, the case sensitivity matters. also in php add `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: i've followed your instructions but no luck. The send message button does not trigger any action after I updated the php code with var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @RobGudipudi you dont get the email?

Comment: No, I'm not even getting the blank email now after adding var_dump($_POST)

Comment: do you receive if you remove it

Comment: Yes, I get the blank email if I remove it

Comment: @RobGudipudi check the php I added

Comment: Thanks. I copy/pasted your PHP and now when I click the Send Message button I get 'post variables are not sent'

Comment: Did you happen to try the code on your server? I get a feeling this is either a jQuery conflict or JSON config in htaccess?

Comment: No but i will test now

Comment: I have updated the main.js code in my question. This has the JQuery for the contact form.

Comment: check the $success value. if its true mail sent otherwise errro.

Comment: @kayra he said it does not reach that part `post variables are not set`

Comment: it need to be debugged for jquery in firebug or something else. see any jquery errors on page.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in main.js:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
```

to:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
```

It will now submit the data.